# Synchronizing pipe access for two way read/write

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux

I have a legacy piece of code where I am delegating certain logic to a child process. The requirement is that parent writes to the pipe and the child reads on it. After reading, child writes something to a new pipe and parent reads from it.

In the code below, function send() is called periodically by a dedicated thread in the parent process.

LaunchWorker() ensures that the child process is forked only on the first call to it.

1) I am not being able to figure out how to close the read and write ends of the two descriptors so that the old data written to the pipe is flushed on every write. 
2) Also is calling pipe() twice needed for the two descriptors?

Any input to make this code work will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

```
typedef struct
{
    WebClient* wc; // user defined class
    string url;
    string data;
    size_t dataLen;
    DownloadObserver* downloadCallback; // user defined class
    string* token;
}Payload;

PayLoad pl;

static pid_t worker_pid = 0;
int fd1[2];
int fd2[2];

bool done = false;

void LaunchWorker()
{
    if (worker_pid != 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    pipe(fd1);
    pipe(fd2);

    worker_pid = fork();

}

void send()
{
    //populate pl;

    LaunchWorker();

    if (worker_pid == 0)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            close(fd1[1]);
            close(fd2[0]);

            int cr = read(fd1[0], &pl, sizeof(Payload));
            if (cr > 0)
            {
                // Upload some data to a remote http endpoint - uses libcurl
                //if upload success, done = true

                int cw = write(fd2[1], &done, sizeof(bool));
                if (cw > 0)
                {
                    // success
                }
                else
                {
                    // failure
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // failure
            }
        }
    }
    else if (workper_pid > 0)
    {
        close(fd1[0]);
        close(fd2[1]);
        int pw = write(fd1[1], &pl, sizeof(Payload));
        if (pw > 0)
        {
            int pr = read(fd2[0], &done, sizeof(bool));
            if (pr > 0) 
            {
                // do something with value read
            }
            else
            {
                // failure
            }
        }
        else
        {
            failure
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you need to call `pipe` twice, to create two pipes. This is because pipes are uni-directional, they are one-way only.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding my first question, any tips on which order I should be calling close() in the code ?

Comment: You should close the descriptors you don't use in each process (e.g. `fd1[1]` in the child process). Other than that you should not need to close any of the pipe descriptors. I'm not sure what kind of "synchronization" you need? Are you sending large amounts of data? What is the size of `Payload`?

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the code with the Payload struct definition and added the calls to close(). sizeof(Payload) is 80. Also please see my comment below to JeremyP's answer for the issue that I am seeing. I am totally lost why would the 2nd read not work.

Comment: One possible problem is that you transfer pointers between the processes. Once the processes split with the `fork` call, they have different memory maps. A pointer to some memory allocated after the `fork` will not be valid in the other process.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to close the unused ends of the pipe *immediately* after the fork, so the parent should close the read end of fd1 and the write end of fd2 and the child should close the write end of fd1 and the read end of fd2. If you don't do this, the pipes will not be closed when you finish.

Then, when you want to stop everything,  I would have the writer of each pipe close the write end of the pipe. i.e.

- parent closes write end of fd1
- child reads eof on fd1 and closes it
- child closes the write end of fd2
- parent reads eof on fd2 and closes it.

Or the other way around if the child initiates shut down.

Finally, the parent process should issue the `wait` system call to collect the exit result of the child.

And yes, you do need two pipes. Pipes are one way.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the code above to show atleast 1)closing of the unwanted descriptors in the two process 2)The definition of Payload struct. The problem that I am seeing at the moment is that on first write/read, everything works fine. The second write is good as well. pl has expected values. However after the second read, when I check the  pl, I still see the same value in pl.url. What could be going wrong on the second (and subsequent) reads ? sizeof(Payload) 80 bytes.

Comment: Just before read() in child, I also allocate memory for pl. 'Payload* pl = (Payload*)malloc(sizeof(Payload));' The size of the second read is also correct - 80 bytes. But I still cant get the second read working. Same issue as above.

Comment: @user2930006 Rather than edit this question to change it, you should create a new question